# How can I render on SSH Linux machine?

Tags: rendering, error, command-line, linux

I downloaded linux version from [this official page](https://www.blender.org/download/) and extracted files onto as folder. Created a very basic default cube file and uploaded it to via WinSCP as well. When I try to execute this line.

```
 ./blender -b untitled.blend -o //file -F JPEG -x 1 -f 1
```

I get this error:

```
/run/user/47130/gvfs/ non-existent directory
Read blend: /home/ogr/b21946658/Blend/untitled.blend
Unable to open a display
Aborted
```

How can this be solved to render a single image or animation?

I also did "*chmod a+x blender*" before these otherwise I was getting *permission denied* error.

I am not admin of this server any solution without sudo would be appriciated.

Comment: Are you rendering with Cycles or EEVEE? EEVEE requires a display to render.

Comment: Guess this helps me, switched to Cycles and it now does work. Any workarounds to render with EEVEE? Also will all the output settings be in the .blend file do I have to put as arguments?

Lastly, how can I learn if I can run on GPU or not?